# count number of rows where value in two columns are both true

Tags: r

I have a dataset with two columns of logicals, and I want to count the number of rows where the value of both columns is true.

Here's a sample dataset with two rows where both values are true:

```
df <- data.frame(
    column_A = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
    column_B = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
)
```

How would I count those two?

I know how to do this with dplyr (filter on the condition of both column A being TRUE and column B being true and then count) but I want to include this inside a function I'm writing and to be honest I don't understand how to do that since dplyr uses non-standard evaluation.

I feel like there's probably a very simple way to do this using a function in base R, but I'm lost and haven't had much luck googling. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple! You can do `sum(df$column_A & df$column_B)`. `df$column_A & df$column_B` returns a logical vector, which can then be fed to `sum()` to determine how many values are `TRUE`.

In case you want to know the indices of the rows where both `column_A` and `column_B` are `TRUE`, you can use `which(df$column_A & df$column_B)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Reduce("&", df[c("column_A", "column_B")])
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rowSums`

```
sum(rowSums(df) == ncol(df))
#[1] 2
```

For doing this for selected columns, we can do

```
cols <- c("column_A", "column_B")
sum(rowSums(df[cols])  == length(cols))
```

---

We can also use `apply`

```
sum(apply(df[cols], 1, all))
```

Or with `dplyr` `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_at(cols, all_vars(.)) %>% nrow
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I used too minimal an example. The actual dataset I'm working with has twentysomething columns of logicals, but I just want to do this comparison for two of them

Comment: @Jeremy updated the answer to do this for selected columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to know for those two columns you can take the sum of the condition:

```
sum(df$column_A & df$column_B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using `tidyverse` (similar to @d.b's `base R` method)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   summarise(out = sum(reduce(., `&`)))
#  out
#1   2
```